# How do I get a certain value related to another two in VB and SQL? (Read more to understand)

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a program with 3 things: Money, Username, Password. The info is stored in a database (MS Access). You should be asked for your username and password at start up, and if you enter them correctly, it will display how much money you currently have (which is a variable; the amount of money could change any time).

My question is the following: What's the query if I want to fetch the "money" related to your username and password? Also, could you tell me the query code for saving the amount of money you currently have to your username and password?

Comment: That rather depends on the design of you database table(s). You will need to update the question with that information and preferably show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question1: What's the Query if I want to fetch the "money" related to your username and password?

lets assume the tablename is 'user'
this is from access

```
SELECT user.money
FROM [user]
WHERE (((user.username)=@user) AND ((user.password)=@pw));
```

Question2: Could you tell me the Query code for saving the amount of money you currently have to your username and password?

i have to guess here i think you mean Update and save to table?

```
UPDATE [user] SET user.money = "500"
WHERE (((user.username)="@user") AND ((user.password)="@pw"));
```

@user and @pw should be replaced of course

that is all i can think of with the little info u prôvided